# There was a problem loading the requested app. the request timed out expo. It looks like you may be using a LAN URL

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, ios-simulator, aws-amplify

I am not able to run my project on IOS simulator using expo on my mac. It was working fine and i cannot see any errors in the code. I see the first screen (Sign-in) where i need to authenticate via google and it is successful in doing that, but after it does not re direct me to the landing page of the app and shows me this message: there was a problem loading the requested app. the request timed out expo. It looks like you may be using a LAN URL. Make sure your device is on the same network as the server, and that you have granted Expo Go the local network permission in the settings app, or try using the tunnel connection type.

I have tried clearing the cache using 'npm start -c', using tunnel connection, and restrating my mac, but nothing is working.

If i remove the sign-in page and directly open the home screen, then it is succesfull. It is just between signing in and home page that I see this message.